# Dynamically building LINQ queries from string

Tags: c#, linq, subset

Here's my scenario:

There is a collection of objects where each object contains a `Dictionary<string, string>`. The user can build a set of queries for this collection from another app to obtain a subset by selecting a `Key` in the `Dictionary`, an operator such as `>` or `CONTAINS`, etc., and a `Value`. They can also balance parenthesis to create groups of queries and select `AND/OR` operators to combine the queries.

As an example, let's say I have a collection of `Car` objects and the `Dictionary` contains keys for `Make`, `Model`, and `Year`.

My app is getting these queries in the form of a string like so:

`"((Make = Honda) AND (Model CONTAINS Civic)) || (Year >= 2015)"`

This tells me that from the collection of `Car` objects that I want cars that have `Dictionary` keys/values of `<Make, Honda>` and `<Model, anything that contains "Civic">` OR `<Year, greater than or equal to 2015>`

So, I parse these out and put them into a `QueryClass` containing three string fields for the `Key`, the `Operator`, and the `Value`. I also keep track of the operator between the queries, and if they are in a group of parentheses or not.

Currently, I have to go through each `QueryClass` one by one performing the query, checking what the previous operator was, if it's part of a group, etc. and combining collections over and over until it reaches the end. This is tedious and seems like an awful way to do things. If there was a way to build these LINQ queries dynamically or perform SQL statements (what these are essential) on this collection it would be better.

Here's my query class that I'm storing the parsed strings in:

```
class QueryClass
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public QueryClass(string pInput)
    {
        var returned = RegexHelpers.SplitKeyValue(pInput); //just returns a string like "Make = Honda" into three parts
        if (returned != null)
        {
            FieldName = returned.Item1;
            Operator = returned.Item2;
            Value = returned.Item3;
        }
    }
}
```

My parsing class is pretty long so I won't post the whole thing but it returns a `List<object>` where each element is either:

- A `QueryClass`
- "AND" or "OR"
- Another List which means it's a group of queries that were grouped by parentheses, containing the two choices above.

Here's an example of the `List<object>` I get after parsing a string:

[image]

I then just loop through each element, determine if the value is a double or string, and execute a LINQ statement on my collection. I'm checking if the operator was "AND" or "OR" (or none if it's just one query), if it's part of a group or not, and combining the results appropriately.

Comment: Good description but please include the code so we can better assess and try to help you!

Comment: Are you aware of Expression trees? From what I know this is basically the technology that makes LINQ to basically anything possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/

Comment: Updated with some code and a pic. @vdL I was not aware of these, I will take a look at them now. Thanks!

Comment: Checkout `System.Linq.Dynamic` nuget library they do a good job in meeting many of these conditions out of box or you surely need `ExpessionTrees` where you can create Binary expression and method call expression to achieve what you are targeting

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail on the class in the collection - specifically, when you say "contains a `Dictionary<string, string>` what does that mean programmatically?

Comment: I would consider using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) that provides helpers for building `Expression` trees for LINQ queries.

Comment: Note that comparing `Year` with string operators is unlikely to work as desired.

Comment: Checkout the answer I have just posted, that provides a step by step way to construct the Linq Expressions and using them in the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my implementation of converting your query into a `Func`. Since I wasn't sure what type was in your collection, I made an interface to represent objects that had an `attributes` `Dictionary<string, string>` and processed that.

Basically I added a method to `QueryClass` to convert it to an `Expression`. It uses a helper dictionary string->lambda that builds the appropriate comparison `Expression` for each operator.
Then I added a class to convert the `List<object>` into a `Func<IItem,bool>` suitable for a LINQ `Where` filter.

```
public interface IItem {
    Dictionary<string, string> attributes { get; set; }
}

class QueryClass {
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public QueryClass(string pInput) {
        var returned = RegexHelpers.SplitKeyValue(pInput); //just returns a string like "Make = Honda" into three parts
        if (returned != null) {
            FieldName = returned.Item1;
            Operator = returned.Item2;
            Value = returned.Item3;
        }
    }

    static MethodInfo getItemMI = typeof(Dictionary<string, string>).GetMethod("get_Item");
    static Dictionary<string, Func<Expression, Expression, Expression>> opTypes = new Dictionary<string, Func<Expression, Expression, Expression>> {
        { "==", (Expression lhs, Expression rhs) => Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, lhs, rhs) },
        { ">=", (Expression lhs, Expression rhs) => Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual, Expression.Call(lhs, typeof(String).GetMethod("CompareTo", new[] { typeof(string) }), rhs), Expression.Constant(0)) },
        { "CONTAINS",  (Expression lhs, Expression rhs) => Expression.Call(lhs, typeof(String).GetMethod("Contains"), rhs) }
    };
    static MemberInfo attribMI = typeof(IItem).GetMember("attributes")[0];

    public Expression AsExpression(ParameterExpression p) {
        var dictField = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(p, attribMI);
        var lhs = Expression.Call(dictField, getItemMI, Expression.Constant(FieldName));
        var rhs = Expression.Constant(Value);

        if (opTypes.TryGetValue(Operator, out var exprMakerFn))
            return exprMakerFn(lhs, rhs);
        else
            throw new InvalidExpressionException($"Unrecognized operator {Operator}");
    }
}

public class LinqBuilder {
    static Type TItems = typeof(IItem);

    static Expression BuildOneLINQ(object term, ParameterExpression parm) {
        switch (term) {
            case QueryClass qc: // d => d[qc.FieldName] qc.Operator qc.Value
                return qc.AsExpression(parm);
            case List<object> subQuery:
                return BuildLINQ(subQuery, parm);
            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    static Expression BuildLINQ(List<object> query, ParameterExpression parm) {
        Expression body = null;
        for (int queryIndex = 0; queryIndex < query.Count; ++queryIndex) {
            var term = query[queryIndex];
            switch (term) {
                case string op:
                    var rhs = BuildOneLINQ(query[++queryIndex], parm);
                    var eop = (op == "AND") ? ExpressionType.AndAlso : ExpressionType.OrElse;
                    body = Expression.MakeBinary(eop, body, rhs);
                    break;
                default:
                    body = BuildOneLINQ(term, parm);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return body;
    }

    public static Func<IItem, bool> BuildLINQ(List<object> query) {
        var parm = Expression.Parameter(TItems, "i");
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<IItem, bool>>(BuildLINQ(query, parm), parm).Compile();
    }
}
```

Once you have this, you can pass in a `List<object>` expression and then filter your collection. Given a query `q` and a collection of `IItem`s `cs`, you can do:

```
var ans = cs.Where(LinqBuilder.BuildLINQ(q));
```

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this problem little differently, since what you are already having is `List<object>`, which internally contain a `QueryClass` containing all the relevant fields containing information, `FieldName`,`Operator` and `Value`, where you are aware which of the binary expressions have to be bundled in a parentheses. Important point is how can you create a Run-time Expression to take care of all kinds of scenarios.

Following is a sample to mimic your scenario:

**Sample Class**

```
public class Car
{
    public string Make {get; set;}

    public string Model {get; set;}

    public int Year {get; set;}
}
```

**Query**

```
((c.Make.Equals("Honda") AndAlso c.Model.Contains("Civic")) Or (c.Year >= 2015))
```

**Linqpad Code**

```
void Main()
{
    var cars = new List<Car>();

    Expression<Func<Car,bool>> e1 = c => c.Make.Equals("Honda");

    Expression<Func<Car,bool>> e2 = c => c.Model.Contains("Civic");

    Expression<Func<Car,bool>> e3 = c => c.Year >= 2015;

    var expr1 = Expression.AndAlso(e1.Body,e2.Body);

    var expr2 = e3;

    var finalExpression = Expression.Or(expr1,expr2.Body);

    finalExpression.Dump();
}
```

**Purpose**

As it can be seen that I have manually constructed the Expressions and finally `Dump` the final expression, since in Linqpad it provides a graphical representation of how shall the Expression be constructed dynamically, overall image is too big and deep to be pasted here (you may try yourself using LinqPad), but following are the relevant details:

1. Create a `ParameterExpression`, this acts as a lambda parameter representing the Car class object (this is independent of the fields of the Query class)

   `var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Car),"c");`
2. Create `MemberExpression` to access each relevant field of the Car class, which is used in the Query (this one needs Field property of the Query class)

   ```
   var makeMemberAccessExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameterExpression, typeof(Car).GetProperty("Make"));

   var modelMemberAccessExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameterExpression, typeof(Car).GetProperty("Model"));

   var yearMemberAccessExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameterExpression, typeof(Car).GetProperty("Year"));
   ```
3. Completing the Expression:

a.) `c => c.Make.Equals("Honda")` we create as follows: (this one needs `Value` property of the `QueryClass`)

```
var makeConstantExpression = Expression.Constant("Honda");

var makeEqualExpression = Expression.Equal(makeMemberAccessExpression, makeConstantExpression);
```

b.) `c.Model.Contains("Civic")` can be represented as follows here we need supply the MethodInfo for the `string Contains` method and create a MethodCallEXpression

```
var modelConstantExpression = Expression.Constant("Civic");

var stringContainsMethodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });

var modelContainsMethodExpression = Expression.Call(modelMemberAccessExpression, stringContainsMethodInfo, modelConstantExpression);
```

c.) `c.Year >= 2015` can simply projected as:

```
var yearConstantExpression = Expression.Constant(2015);

var yearGreaterThanEqualExpression = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(yearMemberAccessExpression, yearConstantExpression);
```

4. Combining all together to form the Composite Expression:

Expressions a.) and b.) are combined together as follows:

```
((c.Make.Equals("Honda") AndAlso c.Model.Contains("Civic"))

var firstExpression = Expression.AndAlso(makeEqualExpression,modelContainsMethodExpression);
```

Expression c.) is independent:

```
c.Year >= 2015
var secondExpression = yearGreaterThanEqualExpression;
```

5. Final `Combined Expression` and Creation a `Func Delegate`

   ```
   // Expressions combined via Or (||)
   var finalCombinedExpression = Expression.Or(firstExpression,secondExpression);

   // Create Lambda Expression
   var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Car,bool>>(finalCombinedExpression, parameterExpression);

   // Create Func delegate via Compilation
   var func = lambda.Compile();
   ```

`func` delegate thus can be used in any of the where clause in the `Linq`, which expects `Func<Car,bool>`

**Design Suggestions**

1. Using the explanation above and values from the Query Class placeholders or directly from the Dictionary it is feasible to create any number of Expressions to be used dynamically in the code, to be compiled and used as a Func delegate
2. Binary expressions like `Equal, GreaterThan, LessThan, LessThanOrEqual,GreaterThanOrEqual` are all exposed by the Expression trees to be used directly, For method like `Contains` available by default you need Reflection to get theb `MethodInfo`, similarly it can be done for the Static methods, just that there's object expressions
3. All Expressions expect values to be supplied Left to Right in the correct order, it cannot be random or incorrect order, else it will fail at run-time.
4. In your case, since you have few queries combined in parentheses and few independent, I would recommend creating multiple `List<Expression>`, where each List is combined in parentheses using `AndAlso` or `OrElse` and each list can thus be combined using `And / Or`

By this approach you shall be able to construct very complex requirements at runtime using Linq Expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Linq Expressions (`System.Linq.Expressions`) and leverage predicates to handle your filtering.

```
public IQueryable<Car> GetCars(Expression<Func<Car, bool>> filter)
{
   return context.Cars.Where(filter);
}
```

That said, the challenge will be to build your predicate expressions based off of your custom `QueryClass` object. To handle the filter on each Dictionary you can create a method to handle each:

```
public Expression<Func<Car, bool>> GetModelFilter(QueryClass modelQuery)
{
    return modelQuery.Operator == "CONTAINS"? car => car.Model.Contains(modelQuery.Value) : car => car.Model == modelQuery.Value;
}
```

Considering you have a limited amount of filters, the above may be acceptable. However, when dealing with a large set this can also be done more dynamically, using reflection or a dynamic predicate builder but for simplicity you can follow the above.

HTH

Comment: Your construction of the Expression tree is not correct as its manual if else, this shall be able to construct the Expression tree automatically, whether Binary or Method Call Expression